# Create a array of structs but define the size later?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to create a array of structs, but define it's size later, like so:

```
struct xy{

int x;
int y;
};

int main(){
    xy pos;
    int size = 10;
    pos = new xy[size];
    pos[0].x = 5;
}
```

But I can't get it to work no matter what I try. Also I don't want to use a vector for this, so please don't say I should.

Comment: "I don't want to use a vector for this." Since you asked that this not be suggested, I won't suggest it, but I will ask: _why_ don't you want to use `std::vector`?

Comment: In `C` you would `malloc` (or maybe Variable Length Arrays in C99) and `free`.

Comment: And for globals, you can even go without dynamic memory: `extern xy pos[]; int const size = 10; xy pos[size];`

Comment: "so please don't say I should" Well, you should.

Comment: When there's a restriction on not using the STL, it's probably for educational purposes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`new` returns a pointer:

```
int main(){
    xy* pos;
    int size = 10;
    pos = new xy[size];
    pos[0].x = 5;
}
```

Comment: The reason Michael's code works and yours doesn't is that the new operator returns a pointer to the first element of the allocated memory. Since xy is a struct type, pos has to be xy*, or a pointer to a struct. This way, if you call pos++, the compiler will know how many bytes to skip to make pos point to the next struct in the array.

Comment: @pajton: Actually, I should have added the words, "but you should use a vector".  I need to sharpen my wit.

Comment: I'd add the `delete[] pos` before the end of the `main`, at least for good practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
xy* pos = new xy[size];
```

Fixed it for you.